# Google analytics on e-commerce (bug?)

Tags: google-analytics

I'm implementing ga on my new ecommerce site before launching it. ga is working flawlesly with all the products, and everything is being recorded fine, checked product by product.

Everything except one thing.

revenue on ecommerce overview.

For some reason, revenue, witch should come from adding per product revenue, keeps adding an almost random huge number.

example:

product1    100.63(unit price)   3(units)
product2     70.50(unit price)   1(units)
product1    115.10(unit price)   2(units)

this data fits perfect with the real data produced by the real order.
BUT 
Revenue says : 10,370.22

Witch doesn't make any sense.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revenue don't

> come from adding per product revenue

Revenue come from the `total` field in `_addTrans` function (see the [doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEcommerce?hl=fr#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addTrans)).